# Aws Elastic Beanstalk not executing cron.yaml file

Tags: amazon-web-services, cron, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I currently have a file cron.yaml in the root of my project.

```
version: 3
cron:
 - name: "shopify"
   url: "/shopify"
   schedule: "0 * * * *"
 - name: "quickbooks"
   url: "/qb'"
   schedule: "0 * * * *"
 - name: "Shopify-Completed"
   url: "/shopify-completed"
   schedule: "0 * * * *"
 - name: "License-Orders"
   url: "/getLicenseOrders"
   schedule: "0 * * * *"
 - name: "Tee-Orders"
   url: "/getTeesOrders"
   schedule: "0 * * * *"
 - name: "Engraved-Orders"
   url: "/getEngravedOrders"
   schedule: "0 * * * *"
 - name: "Engraved-Mexico-Orders"
   url: "/getMexicoEngravedOrders"
   schedule: "0 * * * *"
 - name: "Shopify-All-Orders"
   url: "/pull-shopify-orders"
   schedule: "*/10 * * * *"
```

These are all verified routes in my project.
For example when I manually go to example.com//pull-shopify-orders it executes.
However when it's in cron it's not firing.
Any idea why?

Comment: Are you running worker environment or web one?

Comment: Web one @Marcin

Comment: Also, make sure your routes respond to POST.

Answer (score 1):

`cron.yaml` is only supported for [worker environments](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features-managing-env-tiers.html#worker-periodictasks):

> You can define periodic tasks in a file named cron.yaml in your source bundle to add jobs to your **worker environment**'s queue automatically at a regular interval.

For web environment you have to setup cron "manually" using `.ebextentions`. This is demonstrated in the **recent AWS blog post**:

- [How do I create cron jobs on Amazon EC2 instances in Elastic Beanstalk environments?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cron-job-elastic-beanstalk/)

This involves creating  `cron-linux.config` (example name) file with defined [files](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html#linux-files) and [commands](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html#linux-commands) sections.